# push added object to new array when calling getItems()

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to display(log) the items that I added using the addItems() function when I call(log) the getItems() function..
 console.log(cart.addItem("ITEMMSSS", 100, 10)) << puts out 
ShoppingCart { itemName: 'ITEMMSSS', quantity: 100, price: 10 }
as expected
but the    console.log(cart.getItems()) puts out -1-

when I console.log(this.addedItems) it logs out -undefined-(twice)

I don't understand why I don't have access to the returned value from the 
addItem() function.

```
 class ShoppingCart {

      constructor(itemName, quantity, price) {

        this.itemName = itemName
        this.quantity = quantity
        this.price = price
      }

      addItem(...items) {


        const addedItems = new ShoppingCart(...items)


        return addedItems

      }

    getItems(addedItems) {
            const el = []
        const selected = this.addedItems
         const newArr = el.push(selected)
        return newArr
          }
          clear(...item) {
            // return items.slice(0, ...items).concat(items.slice(...items + 1))
          }

      clone(...items) {

        // console.log(this)

        //  copiedCart.map((item) => {
        // return item
        // })

      }

    }
```

FIXed the issue,

```
class ShoppingCart {

  constructor(items) {

    this.items = []

  }

  addItem(name, quantity, pricePerUnit) {
    const shopCart = this.items.push({
      name: name,
      quantity: quantity,
      pricePerUnit: pricePerUnit
    })

    return shopCart
  }

  getItems(...items) {
    const displayItems = this.items
    return displayItems

  }

  clear(...items) {
    const emptyCart = this.items.length = []
    return emptyCart
  }

  clone(...items) {
    const copyCart = new ShoppingCart()
    copyCart.items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items))
    return copyCart

  }


}


//
// const cart1 = new ShoppingCart('banana', 12, 23)
// const cart2 = cart1.clone()
// //
// console.log(cart2)
// //



module.exports = ShoppingCart;
```

But can't seem to get an immutable copy of the shoppingCart <--
fixed issue after reading about deep copying

```
 clone(...items) {
        const copyCart = new ShoppingCart()
        copyCart.items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items))
        return copyCart

      }
```

Comment: 1. `Array#push()` returns the new length 2. why would a function called `getItems()` actually *add* items?

Comment: `addedItems` is a variable inside your function, you never store it as a instance property (ie on `this`). So `this.addedItems` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple ideas for author to think about:

1) addItem should be a function of an existing instance of ShopppingCart. Creating a new object inside addItems should not be necessary. I only know of returning a value from a setter to be usually only done for "fluent" setters practices so that you can chain them together. But that would be returning the current object.
2) getItems should usually not perform any logic. Usually getters return the current state of a variable / object member.

To address authors direct question:
You are returning the addItems object from the function but not storing it.
Try:

```
cart = cart.addItem("ITEMMSSS", 100, 10)
```